# C# - Convert a text file string to a double array [][]?

Tags: c#, string, double

Help !!! hi people, i have found the following code online that is meant to convert a text file,( with some additional formatting), to a double t[][]. However it states the string input was a incorrect format, is there anyone out there that knows what to do to resolve this? The main code is a deep learning neural net i want to debug and get running, please help i would be willing to share the code once its debugged? Please see below the offending code!

```
public static class DataParser
{

    public static double[][] Parse(string filePath)
    {


        filePath=@"C:\Users\DRS\Desktop\rbm2\SimpleRBM-master\optdigits-tra.txt";
        var x = File.ReadAllText(filePath);

        x = x.Replace("\r\n", "");

       var y = x.Split(" ".ToCharArray());

       var t =
           y. Select(
               s =>
              s.Substring(1).PadRight(1024, '0').Select(
                 n => double.Parse(n.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))).ToArray()).ToArray();

        return t;

    }


}
```

Comment: Is the input file using the format `5.2` or `5,2`?

Comment: Are you referring to this? https://github.com/erezrob/SimpleRBM

Answer (score 1):

You're using LINQ `Select` on a `string`.  When a `string` is used as an `IEnumerable`, you get each character individually.

Then you're converting the character to a string using `ToString(InvariantCulture)`, which is useless.

Finally you're trying to parse this one-character string as a number, which doesn't work out so well when the one character is a `-` or `.`

Calling `ToString()` immediately before `Parse` is always a code smell.  Probably what you meant was to split based on lines, which is best done using the `ReadAllLines` method on the input file.  And then split on whitespace within each line.

```
return File.ReadAllLines(filePath)
                .Select(x => x.Split(' ').Select(double.Parse).ToArray()).ToArray();
```

However, since Maxwell linked your input data in the comments, I can see that you aren't actually trying to parse doubles at all.  Try this:

```
return File.ReadAllLines(filePath).Where(x => x.Length > 10)
                .Select(x => x.ToCharArray().Select(x => x-'0').ToArray()).ToArray();
```

It will be an `int[][]`, reflecting the fact that your digits are binary, no fractions whatsoever.  Also note that I'm simply discarding the annotations about what digit the data actually represents.  What you probably want is a better parser that actually returns a list of (`int[][]`, `char`) pairs that has the bitmap data and annotation for each training input.

Comment: Did you mean something like `.Where(x => x.Length > 10).Select(x => x.ToCharArray().Select(y => y - '0').ToArray()).ToArray();`?

Comment: @Alex: Yes.  Same problem was in both solutions.